# Background service - Internet resource

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager, background-service

In my app, I run a background with walks up every minute with the help of Alarm manager. After walkup, the service calls an API and get destroyed. This structure worked and the app was still running in the background.

But, One day I noticed that the API calls are failing, Even when the app is connected to wifi, (checked internet connection before calling an API and was connected) after I opened and closed the app it was working fine again and the same problem came up after days....this still continues,

I was wondering whether there is a limit to the data that a background service, But I the data I send is so less!

```
    public static void registerAlarm(Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG, "AlarmManager - Registered");

    Intent alarm = new Intent(context, RebootReceiver.class);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if (!alarmRunning && context != null) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 600000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason of those API failures? Do you get any http error code or perhaps an exception with a stacktrace?

Comment: I user OKHTTP and I get an exception saying "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"  - There's is no way the API could fail as it is a GET request from google search engine!!!

Comment: On which device are you testing and what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: minSdkVersion - 21 |
targetSdkVersion - 25 |
 device - google pixel (7.1.2)